# Set/Get Java List<> from C code

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

#### Java Code

In Java code I have class called `IdentificationResult` which has 3 members:

1. `enrollmentID`
2. `enrollmentSettings`
3. `identParams`.

Here is the class:

```
package com.vito.android.framework.service;

class IdentificationResult
{
    class IdentParams {
        byte[] otp;
        String seedId;
    }

    String enrollmentID;
    String enrollmentSettings;
    List<IdentParams> identParams;
}
```

In the main class I have function `IdentificationResult GetAuthenticationStatus(  )`, here is the main Class:

```
public class TokenManager 
{
    /* Some code goes here ... */

    public IdentificationResult GetAuthenticationStatus( )
    {
        /* Function do some actions here ... */
        return new IdentificationResult;
    }
}
```

---

#### C++ Code

I call Java method from my C++ code in this way

```
void GetAuthenticationStatus( )
{
    // Attach current thread.
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    m_javaVM->AttachCurrentThread( env, NULL );
    if( env == NULL ) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass clazz = NULL;
    clazz = env->GetObjectClass( m_classObject );
    if( clazz == NULL ) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Get class method.
    jmethodID clazzMethod = NULL; 
    env->GetMethodID( clazz, "GetAuthenticationStatus", "(V;)Lcom/vito/android/framework/service/IdentificationResult;" );
    if( clazzMethod == NULL ) {
        return VCS_RESULT_ERROR;
    }

    // Call Java 'GetAuthenticationStatus' function.
    jobject methodReturnObj = env->CallObjectMethod( m_classObject, clazzMethod );

    // Get IdentificationResult Class from Object.
    jclass identifyResultClass = env->GetObjectClass( methodReturnObj );
    if( identifyResultClass == NULL ) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Get identParams.
    jfieldID fieldID = env->GetFieldID( identifyResultClass , "identParams", "***1. Question***");
    if( fieldID == NULL ) {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        *** 2. Question *** 
    }

}
```

---

#### Questions

1. What I must write here to get `List<IdentParams>` field ID?
2. How I can Get or Set field value?

Comment: @JoopEggen Can you bring some example code ?

Comment: I started typing, but in fact you have already used all what is needed. You either access the field or make a getter getIdentParams. Sorry but JNI is a terrible verbose coding. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I have solve the problem and want to share result with you, here is solution:

```
    fieldID = env->GetFieldID( identifyResultClass , "identParams", "Ljava/util/List;" );
    if( fieldID != NULL ) 
    {
        // Find "java/util/List" Class (Standard JAVA Class).
        jclass listClass = env->FindClass( "java/util/List" );
        if( listClass == NULL ) {
            DBG_WARNING(DBG_CTX, ("Can't Find Class \"java/util/List\".\n"));
            return -1;
        }

        // Get List object field.
        jobject listObject = env->GetObjectField( methodReturnObj, fieldID );
        if( listObject == NULL ) {
            DBG_WARNING(DBG_CTX, ("Can't get ObjectField for \"List\".\n"));
            return -1;
        }

        // Get "java.util.List.get(int location)" MethodID
        jmethodID getMethodID = env->GetMethodID( listClass, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;" );
        if( getMethodID == NULL ) {
            DBG_WARNING(DBG_CTX, ("Can't get MethodID for \"java.util.List.get(int location)\".\n"));
            return -1;
        }

        // Get "int java.util.List.size()" MethodID
        jmethodID sizeMethodID = env->GetMethodID( listClass, "size", "()I" );
        if( sizeMethodID == NULL ) {
            DBG_WARNING(DBG_CTX, ("Can't get MethodID for \"int java.util.List.size()\".\n"));
            return -1;
        }

        // Call "int java.util.List.size()" method and get count of items in the list.
        int listItemsCount = (int)env->CallIntMethod( listObject, sizeMethodID );
        DBG_DISPLAY(DBG_CTX,("List has %i items\n", listItemsCount));

        for( int i=0; i<listItemsCount; ++i )
        {
            // Call "java.util.List.get" method and get IdentParams object by index.
            jobject identParamsObject = env->CallObjectMethod( listObject, getMethodID, i - 1 );
            if( identParamsObject == NULL )
            {
                DBG_WARNING(DBG_CTX, ("Can't get Object from \"identParamsObject\" at index %i.\n", i - 1));
            }


        }
```

Thanks to @Joop Eggen he gives me great idea !!!

Answer (score 2):

Do not consider the following compilable, but you'll get the idea:

```
jobject list = env->GetObjectField(methodReturnObj, "identParams"); // java.util.List
getMID = env->GetMethodID (listClass, "get","(I)Object");
jobject someIdentParam = env->CallMethod(getMid, new Object[] { list, 0 }); // java.lang.Object
```

Read the documentation first.